# Set sort_link Ransack sort one way asc or desc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

In our system I use Ransack for searching database. In the view I use *sort_link* to sort data. Ransack only use sort_link for both *asc* and *desc* sort. I would like to define two sort_link. one is for sort *asc*. the other is for *desc*.
I tried to set *default_order* but it can't work.

```
sort_link(@q, :post_views_sort, '', default_order: { post_views_sort: 'asc' })
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: <%= sort_link(@q, :post_views_sort, ' ', default_order: :asc) %>

Comment: Thanks @yatindra-rao . It doesn't work. I want the sort_link just sort one way. only sort asc or only sort desc.